# Questions about Active Geo-Replication (and how it interacts with local, within-datacenter, redundancy)

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I just read [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-geo-replication-overview/#termination-of-a-continuous-copy-relationship)[Active Geo-Replication for Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-geo-replication-overview/#termination-of-a-continuous-copy-relationship) article on active geo-replication and have some questions.  I posted these questions on the page with the article but haven't gotten a reply yet.

Could really use help!

1. “Every forced termination results in the irreversible loss of the replication relationship between the primary database and the associated online secondary database.”  What does irreversible mean here?  Does it mean that in order to re-establish a replication relationship between the primary database and an associated online secondary database after a forced termination, we’d need to start over with seeding another online secondary database?
2. “Local data redundancy and operational recovery are standard features for Azure SQL Database. Each database possesses one primary and two local replica databases that reside in the same datacenter, providing high availability within that datacenter. This means that the Active Geo-Replication databases also have redundant replicas. Both the primary and online secondary databases have two secondary replicas.”  So, if we imagine we have active geo-replication up and running and the primary database is lost for some reason.  Will Azure SQL automatically put one of the remaining two local replicas that exist within the same datacenter as part of the standard local data redundancy and operational recovery Azure SQL feature in place of the primary database that was just lost with no impact to existing connections?  If so, I would take that to mean that the only case in which a forced termination of the replication relationship between the primary database and the online secondary (via geo-replication) would only be necessary would be if all 3 copies of the database existing in the local datacenter were lost.  Is that right?
3. Using an active geo-replication configuration, can online secondary databases be in the same region as the primary?  Say we wanted active geo replication within the same region for a time.  Is that doable?  I realize that, from a regional disaster perspective, having online secondaries in the same region would defeat the purpose.  Still would be good to know if it’s doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you force terminate the continuous copy link then a new link must be established to enable Geo-Replication on the new primary database. This would create a new database and start over with the seeding of another online secondary database.
2. Azure SQL Database has [built-in high availability](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-technical-overview/). [Geo-Replication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-business-continuity-design/) (and forced failover) only needs to be used in the event of a disaster causing the entire data center with the primary database (and its replicas) to be unavailable.
3. Active Geo-Replication can be used to scale out read workloads. Active Geo-Replication can be configured in the same region, but the replica must be on a different server than the primary. See "[design pattern 2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-designing-cloud-solutions-for-disaster-recovery/?rnd=1)".

Comment: Thank you!  Re: #2, I need a little more information.  "Local data redundancy and operational recovery are standard features for Azure SQL Database. Each database possesses one primary and two local replica databases that reside in the same datacenter, providing high availability within that datacenter." Local redundancy and operational recovery are not the same as HA.  The question is, if the active DB is lost, and one of the other replicas becomes primary, does that happen automatically, similar to an Availability Group automatic failover?

Answer (score 3):

1. Forced terminate requires you to restart the process of creating active geo replication.
2. You will be able to force terminate if the primary database is unavailable. SQL DB maintains local HA and if one replica down then it switches to a local secondary and built the replacement replica
3. For premium databases you can set up active replication with in the region. This also helps you read scale out.